# Sequence and vectors from CSV file

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I have a CSV file with following columns name.age,salary,experience

When I convert it to a sequence file what exactly happens to the data ?
How does sequence file will look like?

And onc sequence file is converted to vectors how does it look like
I want to understand what happens when we create sequence and vectors from input data

Regards,
Chhaya Vishwakarma

Answer (score 1):

**CSVData file (text) :**

```
vijay@master:~$ hadoop fs -cat /user/vijay/datatext/csvData.csv
vijay,24,22000,2
rami,20,30000,3
kumar,23,400000,11
```

**CSVData SequenceFile(raw form):**

```
vijay@master:~$ hadoop fs -cat /user/vijay/datasequence/p*
SEQ!org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritableorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text▒▒s▒!▒(▒9ŻW▒+fvijay,24,22000,rami,20,30000,umar,23,400000,11vijay
```

(How it looks like ?) - A sequence file has a header which contains information on the key/value class names, version, file format, metadata about the file and sync marker to denote the end of the header. The header is followed by the records which constitute the key/value pairs and their respective lengths.

(What exactly happens ?) - Please read below link which fills all your doubts.

*paragraph credits:https://thinkbiganalytics.com/hadoop-sequence-files-and-a-use-case/*

**CSVData SequenceFile(readable form):**

```
vijay@master:~$ hadoop fs -text /user/vijay/datasequence/p*
0       vijay,24,22000,2
17      rami,20,30000,3
33      kumar,23,400000,11
```

Comment: what about vectors? how do they look ? can i write my own logic for creating vectors?

Comment: If the data is numeric is it require to create vectors ? or is it only required for text data?

Comment: hi sorry for delay, vectors mostly used in Machine Learning. u have to create your own vectors. whether its numeric or text data u should have the final ones to be Doubles i.e, features Double values . you can get much info on vectors from Mahout-In-Action : chapter- 8 Preparing vectors for use by Mahout

Comment: hi,
But in case of logistic regression i saw example of donut.csv there we are not converting data in vector why is it so?

Comment: need of converting the points into vectors purely depends on the algorithm you choose to work on. Vectors are ordered list of points with dimension. In Mahout for some algos purposes, we  use vectors to represent points instead. refer Appendix B in MIAction

Comment: ok thanks for clarification ..we create vectors using a command provided by mahout can i get details anywhere vectors are created when i use a command ? i want to understand what vectors are and how they are created